# Verification Matrices & Linear Equations Part 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations, homogeneous-equation

...Continued

Question 3 
[image]

A - True because if it equals 4 then there will be infinite solutions
B - True because any gradient except for one that is equal (4) will intersect giving a unique solution.

[image]

A - True, not 100% sure why though.
B - False as a homogeneous system when m

[image]

A - True 
B - True as I have Verified by E x E^-1 = I

Thanks in advance for all your time and effort!

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer only the question which's you're not sure  $100\%$:-)

A $m\times n$ matrix $A$ is a representation of a linear transformation
$$f\colon\Bbb R^n\rightarrow \Bbb R^m,\; x\mapsto Ax$$
and if $m<n$ then by rank-nullity theorem $f$ can't be injective and it could be non surjective so if $b\not\in\operatorname{im} f$ then the equation $Ax=b$ hasn't a solution but if $b\in\operatorname{im} f$ then the equation $Ax=b$ has infinity solutions.